# Mysql select query for getting user and follower's posts

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my select query statement:

```
select distinct posts.*, user_status.status_content 
from posts left join user_status on 
user_status.user_id = posts.user_id
where posts.user_id
= $userid or posts.user_id in 
(select follower from follower where follower.user_id = $userid) order by posts.created_at desc;
```

my select query statement works fine, except that the output is not what I exactly want.
what I want is select all post from the current user and his followings, and each posts's user name is their latest `status content`, the status is updated by user, I want select only the latest status content from the table, so how can i do?

posts table:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| content    | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

user_status table:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| user_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| status_content | varchar(225) | YES  |     | Hello World       |       |
| created_date   | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

the user can update thier status, so there will be more than one record in the user_status table.

my select query may output like this:

```
I feel like s**t today!!!!
Hello world
2013-03-28 22:34:14
-----------------------------
I don't feel very good today
Hello world
2013-03-28 22:34:14
```

what I want is, suppose the `I feel like s**t today` is the latest status, so it should output like:

```
 I feel like s**t today!!!!
 Hello world
 2013-03-28 22:34:14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one query that will work regardless of the number of user ids you are looking at.  It calculates the date of the most recent status change, and uses that for a join:

```
select distinct posts.*, user_status.status_content 
from posts left join
     user_status 
     on user_status.user_id = posts.user_id left join
     (select user_id, max(created_at) as maxdate
      from user_status
     ) usmax
     on usmax.user_id = user_status.user_id and usmax.maxdate = user_status.create_at
where posts.user_id = $userid or
      posts.user_id in (select follower from follower where follower.user_id = $userid)
order by posts.created_at desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this clause - `LIMIT 0,1` to your SQL statement. This basically limits the number of results to a maximum of one (which will be the latest post). According to the [MySQL reference manual for SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html), the LIMIT clause is defined as:

The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement.

I would also imagine you'd need an additional order-by clause - something like: `ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC`.

Comment: this will work only if he wants to get for a specific user. what if he wants to get all the latest status for all users? then adding definitely will not work.

Comment: @JW yes, get all the latest status for all users, and all the posts like `twitter`! but the `username` is replaced by `status content`.